# Modelling response with left skewed distribution (upper limit)?

Tags: r, distributions

I would like to model a continuous response which looks like this
[image]

As the instrument had a maximum detection limit (1020 units) lots of experiments have got the maximum measurement.
On my head this is sort of opposite of a zero-inflated distribution.

To recap, which distribution can fit "maximum-inflated" response?

Comment: I believe you should look into censored regression models / Tobit models.

Comment: You're right and indeed there are other postings suggesting to use censored regression. To bring some value in this posting I found extremely useful the below resources,
https://bookdown.org/content/3686/tools-in-the-trunk.html#complex-censoring-when-the-going-gets-tough and 
https://mc-stan.org/docs/stan-users-guide/censored-data.html